# Qt is too large for my capped bandwidth. What are my alternatives?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I want to write a program that has a canvas and users can draw on it with different colors. I found out that Qt has such thing, but when I tried to install it, I realized that it requires 32GBs of installation which is well beyond my bandwidth. I then realized that most of the installation includes things such as MSVC++ which I don't need, and MinGW which I already have. But then again, the modules which remain occupy over 20GB of space. It's not only that I don't have enough bandwidth, my HDD space is low as well, as it's filled to the brim and even my external HDDs are filled to nowheresville. What are my alternatives? Is there a nice, header-only canvas library for C++? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: i use wxwidgets with the object files its at 16gb at the moment for multiple variations of a build using visual studio compiler. if you delete the object files it will only take up 4gb.

Comment: @Yastanub Windows 10.

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez Does it have a canvas?

Comment: did you mean disc space when writing "bandwidth". Bandwidth is related with speed of IO devices (disks, internet, USB) and you are writing about total sizes Qt tools or appliactions.

Comment: @MarekR it's fairly common for internet connections to have a (monthly) limit on total downloads, which is unrelated to the peak bandwidth. Averaged over the whole month, it might be only ~4Kbps (10 GB / 30 * 24 * 60 * 60)

Answer (score 2):

You can build the Qt yourself with the components you need (qtcore + qtwidget)